# perl not found R

Tags: r, perl, call

I am trying to call a perl script in R using the system command
This is what I tried:

```
system("perl R/BEMSER.pl -f R/fasta.txt -m R/matrix.txt -o R/result.txt -tu 100 -tl -100 -c", intern=F)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Warning message:
In system("perl R/BEMSER.pl -f R/fasta.txt -m R/matrix.txt -o R/result.txt -tu 100 -tl -100 -c",  :
  perl not found
```

The command inside the `system` call works in the command line (giving parameters to the perl script, the files perl should use are in a special folder called "R"), perl is of course installed.
What can I do to call the perl script from R?

Comment: Use the full path to `perl`?

Comment: install the `gdata` package and see if running `gdata:::findPerl()` comes back with something.  alternately, ensure the path to `perl` is in your `PATH`.

Comment: Are you by chance on Windows?

Comment: You may type this command on the terminal to find the path to your perl installation's binary, and replace perl with the full path
`which perl`

Comment: @mob If you want to make your script unportable, sure.

Comment: I used: system("C:/Strawberry/perl/bin R/BEMSER.pl -f R/fasta.txt -m R/matrix.txt -o R/result.txt -tu 100 -tl -100 -c", intern=F) returning that it does not find C:/Strawberry/perl/bin. gdata can't find perl and yes, I am on windows (7)

Comment: Dont you want C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl?

Comment: C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl was working. Thanks!